# regex pattern for search

Tags: regex, sed

I need help to write a regex pattern to search and replace using sed :

String to search is of following pattern :

```
string         = "text"
```

basically a string with undetermined white space character followed by some text in " ". I need to replace text using sed.

Comment: And what did you try ?

Comment: what's the expected result?

Comment: sed -i "s#string\(.*\)=.*#string\1= $replace_val#g"

Comment: it replaces quotes also ""

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
's/^\(string *=\).*$/\1'"$replace_val"/
```

`()` need to be escaped `\(\)` to be referenced in replacement part.

`^` means start of the line.

`\(string *=\)` means a group `\( ... \)` of chars made of `string` word and followed with `*` which means 0 or many  (spaces). The sequence of char must end with `=`. This is the first group encountered in the regex, so it can be referenced with `\1` in the replacement part.

`.*$` means any sequence of 0 or many chars up to `$`; the end of line.

If you need to keep the double-quotes:

```
's/^\(string *=\).*$/\1'\""$replace_val"\"/
```

Test of first regex without double-quotes:

```
$ cat properties.txt

# property file
name   =  "smith"

string     = "text"

$ replace_val=stackoverflow
$ cp properties.txt properties2.txt
$ sed -i 's/^\(string *=\).*$/\1'"$replace_val"/ properties.txt
$ cat properties.txt

# property file
name   =  "smith"

string     =stackoverflow
```

Second test with double-quotes:

```
$ sed -i 's/^\(string *=\).*$/\1'\""$replace_val"\"/ properties2.txt
$ cat properties2.txt

# property file
name   =  "smith"

string     ="stackoverflow"
```

Comment: i need to search for the string also. pattern is : string         = "text"

Comment: @Dexter yes Answer had been updated when I undertood that. Refresh and tell me.

Comment: some problem with updated regex. earlier one without string worked but did not match string

Comment: @Dexter I did not found the errors, the tests succeeded on my debian. So, the test session had been added at bottom of the answer.

Comment: @Dexter to troubleshoot, edit the question, and paste the test and its output copied from the terminal session, and add an abstract of the text file used.